Jetpack compose Lazy column with varying negative vertical arrangement
I am implementing a Lazycolumn to display gift cards in a stacked manner. Similar to the Samsung wallet.
    data class GiftCard(
    val giftCardUrl: String = "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    val color: Color = Color.Green,
    val giftCardCode: String = color.hashCode().toString(),
) {
    fun isSameKindAs(other: GiftCard): Boolean {
        return giftCardCode == other.giftCardCode
    }
}

The same gift cards are stacked together (overlapping) with 10.dp padding in between. If the upcoming car a different, then the overlapping padding becomes 30.dp.
@Composable
private fun StackedGiftCards(
    giftCards: List<GiftCard>,
) {
    val cardWidth = 343.dp
    val cardHeight = 219.dp
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp - cardHeight)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(giftCards) { index, giftCard ->
            val paddingTop = when {
                index == 0 -> {
                    0.dp
                }

                !giftCard.isSameKindAs(giftCards[index - 1]) -> {
                    30.dp
                }

                else -> {
                    0.dp
                }
            }
            GiftCard(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(cardWidth)
                    .height(cardHeight)
                    .padding(
                        top = paddingTop
                    ),
                giftCard = giftCard,
                index = index
            )
        }
    }
}


Unfortunately, a LazyColumn only allows a single vertical arrangement of unique spacing.
Does compose allow this at all? Can someone shed some light on this?

You can try using offset modifier for items with negative y value. No need to use negative paddings

I was able to fix this by

provide the least padding between the cards as the default arrangement of the lazy column. In my case, 10.dp
verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp - cardHeight)
Whenever there is a requirement to increase the vertical padding between the items, include a spacer above the item

Column {
 if(isSameKind) {
  Spacer(
    modifier = Modifier
      .height(neededExtraPadding)
   )
 }
 Card()
}

The spacer did the trick for me! Adding just a vertical padding didn't work for my case!
